# Need help with math formula translation

Tags: calculus

I am given the following formula

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j = 1}^{k} r_{ij}||x_i - \mu_j||_2
$$

I want to rewrite the norm in basic algebraic terms. If I understand it correctly, is this the correct formula

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j = 1}^{k} r_{ij}((x_i^2 - 2x_i\mu_j + \mu_j^2))^\frac{1}{2}
$$

Or is this one correct?

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j = 1}^{k} r_{ij}(x_i^2 - 2x_i\mu_j + \mu_j^2)
$$

Comment: Neither, but the second is almost right. Where did the $2$ in $2\mu_j^2$ come from?

Comment: Thanks, @Integrand. I took out the 2. What am I missing in the second?

Comment: What happens when you square a square root?

Comment: It goes away @Integrand

Comment: @Integrand We are not squaring anything though in the initial formula. We are taking L2 norm.

Comment: The two as a superscript usually means "square".  If you want this two to denote $L_2$ norm, probably better as a subscript $|| \cdot ||_2$.

Comment: @mjw I made the change you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Are $x_i$ and $\mu_j$ vectors or scalars?

Comment: $||x_i - \mu_j||_2^2 = (x_i - \mu_j) \cdot (x_i - \mu_j) = ||x_i||_2^2 - 2x_i  \cdot \mu_j + ||\mu_j||_2^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^k r_{ij} ||x_i - \mu_j||_2 
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^k r_{ij} \left[(x_i - \mu_j) \cdot (x_i - \mu_j)\right]^{1/2} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^k r_{ij}  \left( ||x_i||_2^2 - 2x_i  \cdot \mu_j + ||\mu_j||_2^2 \right)^{1/2}
\end{aligned}$$